# Why does the inbox notification in the drop down not refresh automatically?

Tags: discussion, global-inbox, responses

Why should we refresh the page to know if somebody answers, replies or whatever?

Why it doesn't show up by itself?

Comment: It should be visible immediately when you refresh a page. Is this not happening for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? The drop-down menu should show up *everywhere*, no matter where on the network you are. Does it not do that for you?

Comment: why should i refresh the page every time ..whay it doesn't show up by it self?!

Comment: That's a valid question, but then you need to reword what you say. It's not about the notification being *slow* in that case, but about it not turning up until you have reloaded the page

Answer (score 3):

probably this is how it is implemented to reduce server load.

**note:** also consider that some users do not want an automatic refresh of the page...

Comment: Well, it *could* easily be implemented without reloading the page using Ajax.  But it would increase the number of requests for what seems to me is little gain.

Comment: I agree. this is why I throw in the "server load" keyword ;) -> btw, nice re-factoring of the initial question.

Comment: isn't there something like you refresh without flashing .. cause i think the flashing is the annoying thing ..!

Comment: what about the chatrooms it show what they post immediately .. nice & a good move ..!!!

Comment: @jjj "Refresh without flashing" is the Ajax-based implementation that Pekka mentioned in his comment.

Comment: @AnnaLear .. i added my comment before i know that they add  comments ...couse i didn't refresh .. ;)

Comment: Actually this has been raised before, and with the amount of sheer traffic it would require another several servers just to handle the load of checking for new responses, has been the general answer here. Ergo: they won't implement this. Even tho it's a popular request. cc @udo @jjj @pekka @annalear

Comment: @drachenstern: it would be better to add your note to the question. I did not ask it... just tried to give an answer why this request will probably not be implemented.